# Не получается доставать ответы от пользователей в телеграм боте

Tags: python, sql, aiogram

Помогите разобраться с базой данных SQLite, пытаюсь выхватить информацию каждого сообщения пользователя из телеграм бота, но ничего не выходит

Пример ошибки с попытки вытащить первый ответ от пользователя:

```
base_events.py [LINE:1692] #ERROR    [2022-01-25 23:10:01,389]  Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished name='Task-13' coro=<Dispatcher._process_polling_updates() done, defined at C:\Users\max\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py:407> exception=OperationalError('table quiz has 5 columns but 1 values were supplied')>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\max\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 415, in _process_polling_updates
    for responses in itertools.chain.from_iterable(await self.process_updates(updates, fast)):
  File "C:\Users\max\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 235, in process_updates
    return await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
  File "C:\Users\max\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\handler.py", line 116, in notify
    response = await handler_obj.handler(*args, **partial_data)
  File "C:\Users\max\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 256, in process_update
    return await self.message_handlers.notify(update.message)
  File "C:\Users\max\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\handler.py", line 116, in notify
    response = await handler_obj.handler(*args, **partial_data)
  File "C:\Users\max\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\bot_knopki\handlers\users\menu.py", line 31, in menu_2
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO quiz VALUES(?);", answer1,)
sqlite3.OperationalError: table quiz has 5 columns but 1 values were supplied
```

```
import sqlite3
from aiogram import types
from aiogram.dispatcher.filters import Command, Text
from aiogram.types import Message, ReplyKeyboardRemove, message
from bot_knopki.keyboards.default import menu, menu2, menu3, menu4, phonekey
from bot_knopki.loader import dp

@dp.message_handler(Command('start'))
async def start(message: types.Message):
    sti = open('photo_2022-01-24_11-03-21.jpg', 'rb')
    await message.answer_sticker(sti)
    await message.answer("Пройдите тест из 5 вопросов за 1 минуту и получите предварительный расчет стоимости Вашего проекта. "
                         "\nНажми сюда >>> /menu")


@dp.message_handler(Command("menu"))
async def show_menu(message: Message):
    await message.answer("Начнем с того, какая у Вас цель?", reply_markup=menu)
@dp.message_handler(Text(equals=["Нужен чисто сайт или лендинг", "Интересует таргет и продвижение в соц.сетях",
                                    "Неважно что, интересуют заявки и увеличение продаж", 'Необходима консультация']))

async def menu_2(message:Message):
    markup = menu2
    await message.answer("Какого рода у Вас бизнес чтобы понимать какое решение Вам нужно?", reply_markup=markup)
    answer1 = (message.text)
    connect = sqlite3.connect("users.db")
    cursor = connect.cursor()
    cursor.execute(
        "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS quiz( answer1 TEXT, answer2 TEXT, answer3 TEXT, answer4 TEXT, phone TEXT)")
    connect.commit()
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO quiz VALUES(?);", answer1,)
    connect.commit()
    print(message.text)

@dp.message_handler(Text(equals=["Услуги", "Продажа товаров",
                                 "Оба варианта", 'Другой вариант']))
async def menu_3(message: Message):
    await message.answer("Выберите что Вам нужно и мы дополнительно включим это в стоимость.", reply_markup=menu3)
    answer2 = (message.text)
    connect = sqlite3.connect("users.db")
    cursor = connect.cursor()
    cursor.execute(
        "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS quiz( answer1 TEXT, answer2 TEXT, answer3 TEXT, answer4 TEXT, phone TEXT)")
    connect.commit()
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO quiz VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?);", answer2,)
    connect.commit()
    print(message.text)


@dp.message_handler(Text(equals=['Настроить Яндекс Директ', 'Настроить сайт под SEO',
                                 'SMM, таргет', 'Нужна интеграция заявок в телеграм',
                                 'Разработка продающего прайса','Иной полиграфический материал']))
async def menu_4(message: Message):
    await message.answer("Как скоро необходим запуск?", reply_markup=menu4)
    answer3 = (message.text)
    connect = sqlite3.connect("users.db")
    cursor = connect.cursor()
    cursor.execute(
        "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS quiz( answer1 TEXT, answer2 TEXT, answer3 TEXT, answer4 TEXT, phone TEXT)")
    connect.commit()
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO quiz VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?);", answer3,)
    connect.commit()
    print(message.text)


@dp.message_handler(Text(equals=['В течении недели', 'В течении 1 месяца',
                                     'В течении 2-3 месяцев', 'Не к спеху']))
async def end(message: Message):
    await message.answer(f"Будем честными с Вами, после того как заполните форму, приступим к расчету стоимости и подготовке КП для Вас. "
                         f"\nЭто ни к чему не обязывает. Введите пожалуйста номер телефона для связи с Вами", reply_markup=phonekey)
    answer4 = (message.text)
    connect = sqlite3.connect("users.db")
    cursor = connect.cursor()
    cursor.execute(
        "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS quiz( answer1 TEXT, answer2 TEXT, answer3 TEXT, answer4 TEXT, phone TEXT)")
    connect.commit()
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO quiz VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?);", answer4,)
    connect.commit()
    print(message.text)

@dp.message_handler(content_types='contact')
async def contact(message):
    await message.answer('Cпасибо! Ожидайте звонка', reply_markup=ReplyKeyboardRemove())
    if message.contact is not None:
        phone = [message.contact]
        connect = sqlite3.connect("users.db")
        cursor = connect.cursor()
        cursor.execute(
            "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS quiz( answer1 TEXT, answer2 TEXT, answer3 TEXT, answer4 TEXT, phone TEXT)")
        connect.commit()
        cursor.executemany("INSERT INTO quiz VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);", (phone,))
        connect.commit()
        print(message.contact)
```

Comment: как по мне ошибка при записи в бд, а именно в таблице quiz пять колонок, в то время как Вы вносите одно значение

Comment: мне нужно в одну таблицу из разных мест собирать информацию, не пойму как это сделать. Сделать 5 таблиц по одной колонке неудобно

Comment: не работал еще с ботами в телеграмме, поэтому конкретное решение дать не смогу. Вам нужно сначала собрать все данные и потом их внести в бд.
либо вносить в бд записи типа: answer1, Null, Null, Null, Null. а затем не INSERT-ить, а UPDATE-ить